# Spring, Active Directory and workstation : Ldap Error code 351

Tags: spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I've a Java EE application using JSF/Spring 3.1.x. This application use Spring Security to control authentication (users are in an Active Directory).
Everything works fine without workstation restriction defined in the Active Directory (Connection and Credential are valid). But when i add "Workstation restriction" in the Active Directory (like describe here : http://ravingroo.com/267/active-directory-user-workstation-logon-restriction/), i have this error:

```
2013-09-11 15:31:24,978 DEBUG http-bio-172.21.53.136-8080-exec-2 com.societe.commun.web.ConnexionController - org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:263)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:268)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.raiseExceptionForErrorCode(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.handleBindException(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:201)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:182)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:61)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at com.societe.commun.web.ConnexionController.connexion(ConnexionController.java:57)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor128.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:68)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:71)
at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:55)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1028)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:286)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1375)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:752)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Caused by: org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 531, v1db1
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.raiseExceptionForErrorCode(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:220)
... 68 more

Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 531, v1db1
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3067)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3013)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2815)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2729)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:296)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:134)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider$ContextFactory.createContext(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:345)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:179)
```

... 66 more

Ldap error "data 531" means "not permitted to logon at this workstation". But the workstation added is the good one.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

[49 531 1329    ERROR_INVALID_WORKSTATION   Entry not allowed to log on to this computer.](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors)

We have some JN[DI Samples](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/JNDI%20Samples) that work with AD (Assuming you know the proper parameters)

You may find it easier to utilize a LDAP Browser and authenticate with that first then you know what parameters will work. We like [Apache Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

-jim

Comment: Thanks for your help but your link only provide the meaning of 531 sub-codes (already written in my post). Any idea on how to solve it? As i said, the workstation seem to be the good one.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it work was to add the domain controllers to the list of allowed logon workstations.